# system plugin to publish /clock from gazebo 1.7.1 standalone to ROS

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have not installed `simulator_gazebo` in ros-groovy and currently working with gazebo standalone 1.7.1. I need to publish `/clock` as in `simulator_gazebo`. I figured that it was done by the `gazebo_ros_api_plugin`. However, `gazebo_ros_api_plugin` do much more than publishing `/clock` and I isolated the following parts for my purpose. But, still it seems something is missing as /clock is not advertised. Any help would be appreciated.

Also, how do you run the gzclient with this plugin? I tried with `gzclient -g libmy_gazebo_ros_clock.so` and it didnt work.

Thank you

```
#include 

namespace gazebo
{


SystemClock::SystemClock()
{
    this->world_created_ = false;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Destructor
SystemClock::~SystemClock()
{
    event::Events::DisconnectWorldUpdateBegin(this->time_update_event_);
    // Finalize the controller
    this->rosnode_->shutdown();
    delete this->rosnode_;

    // shutdown ros queue
    this->gazebo_callback_queue_thread_->join();
    delete this->gazebo_callback_queue_thread_;
}

/// \brief ros queue thread for this node
void SystemClock::gazeboQueueThread()
{
    ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("Callback thread id=" rosnode_->ok())
    this->gazebo_queue_.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
}

void SystemClock::Load(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // setup ros related
    if (!ros::isInitialized())
        ros::init(argc,argv,"gazebo",ros::init_options::NoSigintHandler);
    else
        ROS_ERROR("Something other than this gazebo_ros_api plugin started ros::init(...), command line arguments may not be parsed properly.");

    this->rosnode_ = new ros::NodeHandle("~");

    /// \brief setup custom callback queue
    gazebo_callback_queue_thread_ = new boost::thread(&SystemClock::gazeboQueueThread,this);

    // below needs the world to be created first
    this->load_gazebo_ros_clock_plugin_event_ = event::Events::ConnectWorldCreated(boost::bind(&SystemClock::LoadGazeboClockPlugin,this,_1));
}

void SystemClock::LoadGazeboClockPlugin(std::string _worldName)
{
    // make sure things are only called once
    event::Events::DisconnectWorldCreated(this->load_gazebo_ros_clock_plugin_event_);
    this->lock_.lock();
    if (this->world_created_)
    {
        this->lock_.unlock();
        return;
    }

    // set flag to true and load this plugin
    this->world_created_ = true;
    this->lock_.unlock();


    this->world = physics::get_world(_worldName);
    if (!this->world)
    {
        ROS_FATAL("cannot load gazebo ros api server plugin, physics::get_world() fails to return world");
        return;
    }

    this->gazebonode_ = transport::NodePtr(new transport::Node());
    this->gazebonode_->Init(_worldName);

    // publish clock for simulated ros time
    pub_clock_ = this->rosnode_->advertise("/clock",10);
    // set param for use_sim_time if not set by user alread
    this->rosnode_->setParam("/use_sim_time", true);

    this->time_update_event_   = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart(boost::bind(&SystemClock::publishSimTime,this));
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// \brief
void SystemClock::publishSimTime(const boost::shared_ptr &msg)
{
    ROS_ERROR("CLOCK2");
    common::Time currentTime = msgs::Convert( msg->sim_time() );
    rosgraph_msgs::Clock ros_time_;
    ros_time_.clock.fromSec(currentTime.Double());
    //  publish time to ros
    this->pub_clock_.publish(ros_time_);
}
void SystemClock::publishSimTime()
{
    common::Time currentTime = this->world->GetSimTime();
    rosgraph_msgs::Clock ros_time_;
    ros_time_.clock.fromSec(currentTime.Double());
    //  publish time to ros
    this->pub_clock_.publish(ros_time_);
}

// Register this plugin with the simulator
GZ_REGISTER_SYSTEM_PLUGIN(SystemClock)

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2733/system-plugin-to-publish-/clock-from-gazebo-1.7.1-standalone-to-ros/) by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 197 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Go to the directory where you have your system plugin and
with

```
gazebo -s libmy_gazebo_ros_clock.so
```

the `/clock` is published OK. And, you may also remove the following parts from the above code, as well.

```
    In SystemClock::~SystemClock()
    // shutdown ros queue
    this->gazebo_callback_queue_thread_->join();
    delete this->gazebo_callback_queue_thread_;

    In SystemClock::Load
    /// \brief setup custom callback queue
    gazebo_callback_queue_thread_ = new boost::thread(&SystemClock::gazeboQueueThread,this);

    /// \brief ros queue thread for this node
    void SystemClock::gazeboQueueThread()
    {
       ROS_DEBUG_STREAM("Callback thread id=" rosnode_->ok())
       this->gazebo_queue_.callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(timeout));
     }
```

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2013-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0